# Webpack's require does work but require.resolve doesn't

Tags: javascript, webpack, bower

Well that's weird, but it happens. I'm trying to use KUTE.js installed from bower, here's the config:

webpack config:

```
var webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    path: './dist',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader' },
      { test: /\.ttf$/, loader: 'file?name=dist/[name].[ext]' },
      { test: require.resolve('zepto'), loader: 'imports?this=>window' },
      { test: require.resolve('KUTE.js'), loader: 'imports?this=>window!expose?KUTE' },
    ],
    plugins: [
       new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            KUTE: "KUTE.js"
       })
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    modulesDirectories: ['node_modules', 'bower_components', 'web_modules']
  }
};
```

My requiring code in src/main.js:

```
require(['zepto', 'KUTE.js', 'KUTE.js/kute-svg'], function() {...});
```

I need that plugin and it depends on KUTE global. The problem is, when I comment out related loader and test resolving (3rd line in loaders), webpack compiles bundle fine, but plugin is unable to load due to missing global. If I leave it as is, I get the standard error:

```
module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'KUTE.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.require.resolve (internal/module.js:16:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/storage/demo/words/webpack.config.js:14:23)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at module.exports (/usr/lib64/node_modules/webpack/bin/convert-argv.js:80:13)
```

And meanwhile:

```
$ ls bower_components
KUTE.js
```

How it can be possible?

Comment: Please create a github repository with exactly what you are trying to do. Or anything we can reproduce the issue.